# Powering down the display in XP with a command

Tags: windows-xp, power-management

Is there a command to power down the display in Windows XP? That is, a command that causes the video card to stop sending a signal to the monitor until input is received, much as power management does after a time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not as far as I know but you can use utilities like [Monitor Off](http://www.dekisoft.com/mou.php) to power down the monitor.

Comment: Excellent. This worked spectacularly.

Comment: The technique behind this is explained at codeproject here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/display_states.aspx

Answer (score 20):

There is also a utility called [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), which supports not only this but more commands (like changing system volume, manipulating services etc - documented in the page linked). Usage is via the command line:

```
nircmd monitor off
```

And sometimes I've seen Windows "listening" to your last keystroke (the Return that confirms the command) after the command is "issued" and waking back up. A solution that has worked for me in most cases is:

```
nircmd cmdwait 1000 monitor off
```

**Disclaimer:** although this may be the third or fourth time I mention it here, I have no association to the NirCmd's team: just a happy user.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like nircmd can be used to turn off a single monitor (in a multi monitor setup)

Answer (score 1):

### Turn off display by shortcut

**Why this script is good?**

> Display will sleep again in **3 sec**
>   Even if mouse by accident was moved or any program waked display up.

How-to:

1. Download Gist as ZIP
2. Unpack & run
3. Link **Display Sleep!** <s>will</s> should be created.

[Github-Gist / setup_display_timeout.cmd](https://gist.github.com/Befzz/0a4687cf2daf4c323899)

---

How it works:

1. Set idle timeout to **3 seconds** (via Powercfg)
2. Wait for **any key press**
3. Set idle timeout to **1 hour**

Part of code:

```
powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX %current_scheme_token% SUB_VIDEO VIDEOIDLE %seconds%
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX %current_scheme_token% SUB_VIDEO VIDEOIDLE %seconds%
powercfg /S %current_scheme_token%
```