# Is there a way to shut off a laptop monitor?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display

I tend to leave Skype calls on overnight, and for some reason Skype overrides my computer going idle. I have no idea why this is; it prevents Pidgin from idling, as well as some other programs, and prevents my computer from going into power-saving turning off the monitor.

Anyway, is there a way to manually turn the monitor off on a laptop in Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running Windows, try the tool in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/127633/powering-down-the-display-in-xp-with-a-command/127634#127634).

Comment: Ooh, fancy. I was hoping for something I could type on command line or in a batch file, but this has the option to set to a hotkey. Very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You have tagged the question 'Windows 7', but just to mention the Linux solution if you are using X - `xset dpms force off`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Portable little tool [MonitorES](http://code.google.com/p/monitores/).

> MonitorES is a small Windows utility that helps you to turn off monitor
>   display when you lock down your machine. Also when you lock your
>   machine, it will pause all your running media programs & set your IM
>   status message to "Away" / Custom message (via options) and restore it
>   back to normal when you back.