# Is there a switch box that could connect 1 monitor to both my laptop and desktop?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I share a monitor between two computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/156058/how-can-i-share-a-monitor-between-two-computers)

I have a desktop and laptop on the same table, and I only use 1 of them at the same time.

I have an monitor that I would like to use for both my laptop and desktop.

Is there some kind of a switch box that I could connect my monitor to, and both my laptop and desktop and then simply flip a switch so either my laptop or desktop uses the monitor?

Answer (score 4):

It's called a KVM switch, Keyboard Video Mouse. You can get them as USB or PS/2, and as VGA or DVI. There are even expensive ones that duplicate dual monitors as well

Comment: DVI ones seem to be way more expensive!

Comment: Because of the quality... DVI has a higher throughput than a VGA cable

Answer (score 1):

If you have a laptop and a desktop running Windows you're probably wisest to stick with the USB/VGA combo. If they're both Macs you will ned to be careful about the laptop's video out. With the larger older laptops it's usually standard DVI, but the Macbooks and iBooks need an adaptor to VGA or DVI. It then depends on what the desktop is and has.
It sounds complicated, but you just need to check all the possible connections. There are adaptors PS/2 to USB (but not the other way about).
Paul

Comment: its macbook to pc desktop, but are using DVI (yes the mac has the DVI extension plug)

Answer (score 0):

Some monitors have more than one input and the ability to select between them using the 'source' button.  If you have such a monitor, you may be able to get better video bandwidth (clearer images / text at the highest resolution that the monitor is capable of) by connecting both to one monitor.

Comment: I have a samsung 2494 HM, and I see a label 'source' on the front..hmmm :)